# Stack throwing errors whenever I try to install something

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Whenever I try to install something with `stack`, for example `$ stack install hip`, `$ stack install Gifcurry`, and several other packages, they all throw the same error:

```
Downloaded lts-12.9 build plan.
AesonException "Error in $.packages.cassava.constraints.flags['bytestring--lt-0_10_4']: Invalid flag name: \"bytestring--lt-0_10_4\""
```

This is the first time I've tried using `stack` to install anything, so I'm not sure what to do. I did run `$ stack upgrade` before doing this.

The Stack version is `1.5.1 x86_64` and it is in the directory `usr/bin/stack`.

Comment: If you run `which stack` and `stack --version`, what does it show?  A potential issue is that `stack upgrade` normally installs the new version in `~/.local/bin/stack`, but you may be using an old version in `/usr/local/bin/stack` or someplace similar.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr version is `1.5.1 x86_64` and the folder is `usr/bin/stack`

Comment: You need a more recent version of Stack (1.6.1 or above). Cf. [*Cannot build a hello world program with Stack because of flag bytestring--lt-0_10_4*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47962377/2751851)

Comment: @duplode thanks, how do I get the new version if not by `stack upgrade`?

Comment: `stack upgrade` installs Stack in `~/.local/bin`. It seems the globally installed version is being picked ahead of the local one, so you'll likely want to have a look at your PATH.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a common problem, but it's a little tough to find a StackOverflow answer that addresses it directly, so here's a shot at it.

On Linux, there are two main ways to initially install Stack:

1. If your distribution has a "stack" package, you might install that.  This will usually put the `stack` binary in `/usr/bin/stack`.
2. If you follow the instructions on `haskellstack.org`, it'll tell you to retrieve an installation script via `curl` and pipe it through a shell:  `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh`.  By default, this puts `stack` in `/usr/local/bin/stack`.

Most people already have these directories in their paths, so they don't have any problem running `stack` after installation, in either case.

**HOWEVER**, if you later follow the instructions for upgrading Stack using the `stack upgrade` command, this will install the upgraded binary in your home directory under `~/.local/bin/stack`.   The old version in `/usr/bin/stack` or `/usr/local/bin/stack` will be left untouched.

Since many people do *not* have `~/.local/bin/` in their path, they may find that attempts to run Stack after supposedly upgrading it will still run the old version.  If you run:

```
$ which stack
/usr/local/bin/stack
```

and see that the path is the globally installed version instead of something under your home directory, like `/home/xxx/.local/bin/stack`, then you're probably still running the old version.

If you try running:

```
$ ~/.local/bin/stack install hip
```

and that works, then that will confirm that this is your problem.  You'll have to add `$HOME/.local/bin` to your path *before* the global paths to select the correct version of `stack`.  (If you haven't done this sort of thing before, search for "adding directory path" and your Linux distribution.  For example, here are some [instructions for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) on the Ask Ubuntu StackExchange site.)